# Flutter Error - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

Yesterday, I ran my app just for check before go to bed. Suddenly, the problem appeared and I tried almost everything in stackoverflow to fix it but none of them can solve the problem. This problem appeared literally "suddenly". I'm so confused now, because I didn't do anything before I ran the app. There were not a single change in my app after I checked the app which is 5 minutes before. But now, it just can be built whatever I do. Please give me any suggestion, and I will do it. Here is Error messages.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/Documents/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1156

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/Documents/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


***and here is flutter doctor result***



[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.2, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64)
    • Flutter version 3.0.2 at /Users/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cd41fdd495 (6 days ago), 2022-06-08 09:52:13 -0700
    • Engine revision f15f824b57
    • Dart version 2.17.3
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.66.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/Downloads/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • macOS (desktop)   • macos       • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.61

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

**First** run `flutter clean`

**then** open only the android project folder using android studio,
android studio will start syncing your project grade.
(it may take some time depending on the internet speed)

if the android studio did not start to sync you by itself or fail during this, click the sync button.

[image]

**return back to your flutter project** run `flutter pub get` and try to run the app.

Answer (score 0):

- First `flutter clean`
- Then run `flutter pub get`
- Then run `flutter pub upgrade`
- Then try and run the dart migrate.
- And check your build gradle for no mistakes

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'Then try and run the dart migrate'. Are you possibly referring to dart fix --dry-run? Regardless, the first three steps you mentioned were really helpful in resolving the bug that caused my build to hang at compiling item 15 out of 35, and seemingly count time indefinitely. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I finally success to run the app! I just deleted all files and updated android studio, and cloned my app from github and ran again. It worked! But I really don't know what caused this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).